# Dynamically adjust canvas to fit image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

My code will open a local image into a canvas. This is a responsive page so the canvas resizes dynamically depending on the window size. I need to be able to get the dimensions of the image being loaded, get the current size of the canvas and proportionally resize the image to fit in the canvas. I am trying to write this all in HTML5, CSS3, JQuery and Javascript, but don't know how to do it. Here is the code I have so far.

**CSS**

```
#main{ display:block; width:99%; border: 5px solid #0C0; }`
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script> //Loads the local file
 $(function() {
$('#file-input').change(function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0],
        imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType))
        return;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = fileOnload;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);});

function fileOnload(e) {
    var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    $img.load(function() {
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    });
}
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> //Resizes the canvas
$(document).ready( function(){

    //Get the canvas & context
    var c = $('#canvas');
    var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var container = $(c).parent();

    //Run function when browser  resize
    $(window).resize( canvas );

    function canvas(){
        c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
        c.attr('height', $(container).height() ); //max height

        //Redraw & reposition content
        var x = c.width();
        var y = c.height();             

        ct.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"; //white
        ct.fillRect( 0, 0, x, y); //fill the canvas
    }

    //Initial call
    canvas();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="file-input" type="file" /> //Loads the image

<div id="main" role="main"> //The canvas
                <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
```

Comment: Would [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/afvkq0p7/) work for you? If it does, I'll make an answer, just resize the window's width to see it work.

Comment: Rou,That does work but I don't really want to have to put an instruction to the visitor to resize the window to get their image to fit in the window. Is there any way to get the image to fit without that first resize?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't notice that because I was using a smaller image, [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/o8xgf2yf/).

Comment: Rou, I have tried the second script you posted on MAC and Windows and 3 different browsers. None of them will show a large image completely **until** you resize the browser. Isn't there a way to make it show the entire image without having to resize the browser first?

Comment: I'm sorry you had to try all that, I just typed the wrong function and mistakenly thought I fixed it, [**this should work now**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxaac7y0/). Sorry for causing you problems :)